# Future of Socket Programming and HTML5 WebSocket and REST Combined

Tags: html, sockets, architecture, websocket, phpwebsocket

I have created simple Socket Server in PHP and Make Chat Application with that.

Socket server working on some port e.g. 127.0.0.1:9999
All clients connect with that IP:PORT and Shake-hand to server and communicate with each other.

My Concept:

1) `Browser` => Get Real-time Notifications by ( WebSocket )
2) `User` => Post Comments ( Want to Save Comment in Database either using REST or simple )
        After saving my Post to Database It should be broadcast to all users GUI without any `HTTP Request` ( By Only WebSocket ).

So, My question is regarding, How to handle Second Part when User post comment inside my `WebSocketServer`.

Comment: -1 also allow but, I need solutions architecture from people who are are architect.

Comment: What REST technology are you using?

Comment: PHP with REST Technology

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you might have in mind is something like this:

`Browser
   |
   +----> REST/HTTP ---> Web Server (REST)
   |                         |
   |                        (*)
   |                         |
   |                         v
   +-<--- WebSocket <--- WebSocket Server`

The browser does REST/HTTP requests, and at the same time maintains a WebSocket connection to receive real-time notifications.

The browser does REST/CRUD requests to your Web/REST server, and when the REST server performs a CRUD operation, it not only answers to the requestor, but also sends out notification to others via WebSocket.

There are 2 important aspects:

First, WebSocket isn't enough, since it is only raw point-to-point messaging). You likely want some "Publish & Subscribe" schema *on top of WebSocket*, so that the CRUD operation on a given resource can send out a notification only to those browser/WebSocket clients that are interested and allowed to receive notification for the respective resource.

Second, depending on the technology of your Web server, you want to make the (*) as easy as possible (e.g. doing (*) by a simple HTTP request *from* your Web server *to* the WebSocket server).

Both of above is provided e.g. by [Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io/):

- Crossbar.io is a [WAMP](http://wamp.ws/) router, and WAMP ("The Web Application Messaging Protocol") provides "publish & subscribe" over WebSocket.
- Crossbar.io has a builtin HTTP-to-WAMP bridge that allows you to publish by doing a plain old HTTP request.

Please see [here](http://crossbar.io/docs/HTTP-Pusher-Service/) for an example.

Disclosure: I am affiliated with WAMP and Crossbar.io.

Comment: Please check my updated questions detail

Comment: Note that in the diagram above, the notification *is* over WebSocket. It's only the ( * ) that is using HTTP. If you want to get rid of ( * ), you will need a Web server technology that can run WebSocket natively.